add value to key within jolt
within jolt I try to transform the following jolt
Input :
{
  "id" : "76a3f8ae311327d684133d29fc620a7d",
  "property.country_of_origin.0" : "TW",
  "property.colour.0" : "black",
  "property.colour.1" : "orange"
}

Expected Output :
{
  "id": "76a3f8ae311327d684133d29fc620a7d",
  "properties": [
    {
      "id": "property.country_of_origin.TW"
    },
    {
      "id": "property.colour.black"
    },
    {
      "id": "property.colour.orange"
    }
  ]
}

That means, that the value of a property* should become the last part of the key ("TW" instead of 0, "orange" instead of 1 etc). After this transformation, this key should appear as value after "id" as a single object within a properties-Array.
Any help or hint would be highly appreciated.

The trick is separating the left hand side by dots while using concatenation operators for combining the dot separated pieces of the keys such as
[
  {//derive independent "id" arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "*.*.*": {
        "*": {
          "$(1,1)|$(1,2)|@1": "&2.id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "*y.*": {
        "@": "&(1,1)ies[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {//concatenate the components of the "id" arrays
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "p*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=join('.',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site Jolt Transform Demo Using v0.1.1 is :


Amazing Barbaros. Thank you so much.
